# issue in Laravel DB query with search data and count

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, search

I want to search username in user's table and I have **count members in member's table**. And group's table is main table. members table in multiple entry of group members. but I can't be Search Username and count of  Members both in one query. my query is below

```
$group = Group::select('groups.*', DB::raw('count(group_id) as totalMembers'), 'users.name as ownerName', 'users.id as userId')
            ->leftJoin('members', 'members.group_id', '=', 'groups.id')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'members.user_id')
            ->where('members.memberStatus', 'Joined')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('name', "like", "%" . $request->searchText . "%");
                $query->orWhere('groupName', "like", "%" . $request->searchText . "%");            
            })
            ->groupBy('groups.id')
            ->get();
```

In this query members of count is not getting proper, but search is working
my table structure is below

**users table**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmEI8.png)

**members table**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz1Zb.png)

**group tables**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9BVI.png)

Comment: `DB::raw('count(members.group_id) as totalMembers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this subquery**

```
$group = Group::select(['groups.*', 
                        'users.name as ownerName', 
                        'users.id as userId',
                        \DB::raw("(SELECT count(members.group_id) FROM members
                            WHERE members.group_id = groups.id
                            GROUP BY members.group_id) as totalMembers")])
            ->leftJoin('members', 'members.group_id', '=', 'groups.id')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'members.user_id')
            ->where('members.memberStatus', 'Joined')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('name', "like", "%" . $request->searchText . "%");
                $query->orWhere('groupName', "like", "%" . $request->searchText . "%");            
            })
            ->groupBy('groups.id')
            ->get();
```

**OR**

```
DB::raw('count(members.group_id) as totalMembers
```